# How can I have long text in a single line excel cell?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I'm generating excel sheet using jasper report. A cell can contain long text and I found that it was cut the text to fit the cell width.

The parameter `isStrechWithOverflow="true"` partially solve the problem, but I do **not want to change cell dimension**, I'd like to have long text in the single line cell.

Is possible at all ? I believe I've tried all the options

Comment: Can you illustrate the requirements with help of images? You should also post your test *jrxml*

Comment: Consider to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer on your question (this is done by checking green check next to the answer that you like to accept)

Answer (score 2):

Your are looking for these property's:

[net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row). and [net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text)

This way you can leave `isStrechWithOverflow="true"` (for other exports) on the textField's.

`<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="false"/>` to avoid that row is fitted.

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="SimpleTest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="e4188d8a-c7f9-4f7d-8f0f-ada07b89d42f">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" value="false"/>
 ... here goes the rest of your report

</jasperReport>
```

*Note: the settings on the `jasperReport` tag in example are arbitrary*

Comment: It didn't solve the issue but helped me so I tested other properties and found that settings
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" value="false"/>
at the reportElement level and and isStrechWithOverflow="false" are what I had to do

Comment: @ra74 I have included your net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text property in answer the difference from using print.keep.full.text = true and xls.auto.fit.row=false is that xls.auto.fit.row only have affect on excel (so it does not mess up other types of reports.)

Answer (score 0):

Add this property 
net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text = true in your jrxml. By default this value is set to false.

Refer [this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/527348/excel-row-content-gets-cut) to see more information